# String to two numbers

Tags: c++, string, int

I need help creating a function that accepts a string containing two numbers separated by " "(space). These two numbers then are passed to another function to create a fraction format out of it.

I've tried an if statement locating the space then creating two substrings containing values before and after the space character respectively.

```
Fraction::Fraction(string frac)
    {
            int t, b;
        for (int i = 0; i < frac.size(); i++)
        {
            if (frac.substr(i, 1)==" ")
            {
            t = stoi(frac.substr(0,i-1)); //number before space
            b = stoi(frac.substr(i + 1)); //number after space
            break;
            }
        }
        this->setFraction(t, b);
    }
```

For example, string s="1 2" converts into t=1 and b=2.

Comment: There's no need for that `substr(i, 1)` dance. That's expensive. Just use `frac[i]` to access the i'th character in `frac`. Or use `frac.find(' ')` instead of writing your own loop.

Comment: This can be done much more simply with [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream#Locales).

Comment: Beware that if there are no spaces in your string, `t` and `b` are left uninitialized.

Comment: @PeteBecker you mean [std::istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) ;-)

Comment: @bruno — yup. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are in C++, just use *std::istringstream* :

```
std::string s("1 2");
std::istringstream ss(s);
int t, b;

if (ss >> t >> b)
  std::cout << t << '/' << b << std::endl;
else
  std::cerr << "invalid form " << s << std::endl;
```

else if you want you can use C *sscanf* on `string::c_str()`

```
std::string s("1 2");
int t, b;

if (sscanf(s.c_str(), "%d %d", &t, &b) == 2)
  std::cout << t << '/' << b << std::endl;
else
  std::cerr << "invalid form " << s << std::endl;
```

It is useless to complicate your life, and that allows to manage case with additional spaces/tab.

But I encourage you to always check if your get a result, not to suppose/hope you got one

Comment: I used the C++ way and changed some lines to fit my problem and it works. :D thank you!